# Service Worker not caching files when React app is deployed

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm making a React PWA which works fine on localhost to cache all the listed files but when I deploy the project on Netlify or any other platform it won't cache the files and is not working offline. The cache storage shows empty list which in case of localhost shows all the files I'm caching. The service worker file is being registered in both cases.
[image: This is localhost version]
[image: This is deployed version]

The link to my github repo is here:
https://github.com/noumanmalik960/quiz-app-pwa

Here is service worker file code:

```
const CACHE_NAME = "cache-v1"
const urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/static/js/bundle.js',
  '/static/js/0.chunk.js',
  '/static/js/main.chunk.js',
  '/manifest.json',
  '/static/media/bg.759ecf3a.jpg',
  '/images/logo.png'
]


self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  if (!navigator.onLine) {

    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response)
            return response;
          return fetch(event.request);
        })
    )
  }


})
```

Comment: Please share your netlify deployment url.

Comment: In your filesToCache in service worker , you need to append your netlify deployment url.

Comment: @VimalPatel I have appended the list with "`https://quiz-pwa-knowmi.netlify.app/`", that is my netlify deployment link but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your cache list is empty as few of the files which you mentioned in your cache list does not exist. Check below screenshot.
If any of the files which you have mentioned in your cached List (in your service worker) is missing or browser not able to find that then it will create the cache entry but will not be able to cache any files.

[image: Errors]

Fix your above mentioned files url and then your service worker will work as expected.

Comment: \I have removed all the files from cache list except "index.html" but on deployment it still is showing nothing cached, but in case of localhost it is caching the files just fine.

Comment: I can see that Index.html file in cached list under "version-1".

Comment: Also, please add below files in your cache list so that your app can work in offline mode.
2.d7a32088.chunk.js,
main.cace1e96.chunk.js,
react_devtools_backend.js,
inject.js

Comment: So I was caching the wrong files I guess, cached the files you've mentioned and it worked. Thank you!